# Upright/Horizontal labels when labeling circular polygons at perimeter?

Tags: qgis, qgis-2

I have several polygons (circles) I want to label with their ID number. The label should be outside the circles so I use the positioning options "Use perimeter" and the tickbox "Next to the line (or similar, my qgis talk spanish...).

QGIS now automatically aligns the labels with the curvature of the line. Is there an option or a way to make them oriented horizontally?

Answer (score 2):

There is currently no option to keep the labels horizontal for perimeter placement.

However, you can use the **Around centroid** placement and set an expression that calculates the radius for the circle and uses that for the label's distance from the circle's center:

[image]

**Relevant settings:**

*Centroid* = whole polygon, or canvas-extent-clipped polygons will return odd calculation results for distance

*Distance* = data defined override expression for circle radius (you can add an extra buffer in map units, if desired):

```
$perimeter / (2 * $pi)
```

*Distance units* = map units

NOTE: This expression only works for your use case of circular polygons.