# In QGIS, how do you place horizontal label outside polygon border?

Tags: qgis, labeling

I am attempting to recreate a layout from ArcGIS in QGIS.  One of the advanced label options in ArcGIS is to force horizontal labels outside a polygon.  You can optionally choose which quadrant the labels fall in.
[image: Horizontal label outside polygon - ArcGIS]

This question is related, but the labels are parallel with the polygon perimeter:  [Labels outside polygons in ArcMap](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/138097/labeling-outside-polygon-using-qgis)

The answer to this question is basically what I'm looking for, but my polygons aren't circles:  [Upright/Horizontal labels when labeling polygons at perimeter in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/91300/upright-horizontal-lables-when-labeling-polygons-at-perimeter)
That question was asked in 2014, so perhaps a solution has been found in ensuing years?  I am fine with prioritizing a quadrant for location, if that would help.

Answer (score 6):

Facing a similar issue, I applied in Placemente/Data Defined the following expressions:

For X coordinate:

```
x( closest_point( $geometry, make_point(  x_max($geometry),(  y_min( $geometry )))))+20
```

For Y coordinate:

```
y( closest_point( $geometry, make_point(  x_max($geometry),(  y_min( $geometry )))))-15
```

In this case, the label is at the bottom right of the polygon. The constants (+20 and -15) can be adapted depending on the scale, but it works for all features automatically

Answer (score 5):

I'm using QGIS 2.18.4

You can create a virtual layer importing your polygons by a buffer distance (and keeping your label field):

[image]

And then label like this:

[image]

You will end up with this (I'm adding the buffer outline so you can see it but you can set it to transparent):

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, there is no automatic way to place the labels outside the polygons and keep them horizontally. After several tests, I found two ways to do that, but both of them are time consuming:

1. Using Rule based Labeling

   - You to define each label individually, and use `Placement` -> `Data Defined` -> `Coordinate X` and enter the following formula:

     ```
     x(bounds($geometry))+ Constant
     ```

     `Placement` -> `Data Defined` -> `Coordinate y` and enter the following formula:

     ```
     y(bounds($geometry))+ Constant
     ```

     Where `constant` is an offset value to shift the label outside the polygon, thus, you need to adjust the constant for each individual label.
   - I used Alignment `horizontal` and `vertical` and wrote `'Center'`and `'Cap'`, respectively.

[image]

Here is the result:

[image]

2. The second option is to add x and y fields in the attribute table, then go to `Placement` -> `Data Defined` -> `Coordinate X` and `Coordinate y`, and  select x field and y field, respectively. Then start editing and move the labels manually outside each polygon.

As I said at the top of my answers, both solutions are not efficient. But I hope the developer team can add this option in the next releases.

Comment: This is the same as in the first answer I referenced.  I do not want to follow the curvature, but to have the labels horizontal, as similar to the 2nd link I referenced.  That answer doesn't work though because my polygons are not circles.

Comment: I misunderstood your question, I thought you want the labels to follow the curvature of the polygon.

Comment: I updated my answer.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly, you can do like this:

[image]

Keep in mind that using curved labels will not show up too long laybels.

Answer (score 2):

This is an answer to an old question, but placement of labels outside polygons will become a standard option in QGIS 3.14 per [PR #36106](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/pull/36106)